# Alternative of too many fields in elasticsearch document

Tags: elasticsearch

I am using elasticsearch 5 version. They have set a
 [limit on maximum no of fields in an index.](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.6/mapping.html)

> The maximum number of fields in an index. The default value is 1000.

I have a _type named 'customer' in the _index 'company', 
**customer** can have too many fileds (say 2000) in its doc.

### Solution1:

We can achieve above requirement by changing in **company** setting as below

```
PUT company/_settings
{
  "index.mapping.total_fields.limit": 2000
}
```

and then put the mapping of **customer** like:

```
PUT /company/_mapping/customer
{
   "customer": {
      "properties": {
         "property1": {
            "type": "text"
         },
         "property2": {
            "type": "text"
         },
         .
         .
         .
         "property2000": {
            "type": "text"
         }
      }
   }
}
```

### Problem:

Above solution leads to data sparsity problem, since each customer doesn't have all the properties.

### Solution2:

We can create a separate _type for customer properties(say **custom_props**) with following mapping

```
PUT /company/_mapping/custom_props
{
   "custom_props": {
      "_parent": {
         "type": "customer"
      },
      "_routing": {
         "required": true
      },
      "properties": {
         "property_name": {
            "type": "text"
         },
         "property_value": {
            "type": "text"
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Now each property of customer will have a separate doc in custom_props.

### Problem:

When searching for a particular customer with certain properties we need to make has_child query and some time has_child query with inner_hits in some use cases. As per ES documentation these queries are much slower than simple search queries.

> So I want a best alternative of solving this problem when we have too
>   many fields in our elasticsearch _index.

Answer (score 2):

There is one type of [handling relations](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/relations.html) in Elasticsearch that you didn't consider: [nested objects](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/nested-objects.html). They are similar to parent/child but [usually has better query performance](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/choosing-parent-child-vs-nested-document/6742/2).

With nested data type the mapping might look like this:

```
PUT /company/
{
  "mappings": {
    "customer": {
      "properties": {
        "commonProperty": {
          "type": "text"
        },
        "customerSpecific": {
          "type": "nested",
          "properties": {
            "property_name": {
              "type": "keyword"
            },
            "property_value": {
              "type": "text"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Let's see how will a document look like:

```
POST /company/customer/1
{
  "commonProperty": "companyID1",
  "customerSpecific": [
    {
      "property_name": "name",
      "property_value": "John Doe"
    },
    {
      "property_name": "address",
      "property_value": "Simple Rd, 112"
    }
  ]
}

POST /company/customer/2
{
  "commonProperty": "companyID1",
  "customerSpecific": [
    {
      "property_name": "name",
      "property_value": "Jane Adams"
    },
    {
      "property_name": "address",
      "property_value": "42 St., 15"
    }
  ]
}
```

To be able to query such data we will have to use a [nested query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.6/nested.html). For instance, to find a customer with name `"John"` we might use a query like this:

```
POST /company/customer/_search
{
  "query": {
    "nested": {
      "path": "customerSpecific",
      "query": {
        "bool": {
          "must": [
            {
              "term": {
                "customerSpecific.property_name": "name"
              }
            },
            {
              "match": {
                "customerSpecific.property_value": "John"
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: thanks for your reply... nested document can be a solution also, but the problem is that whenever there is any updation in customerSpecifix property then ES will reindex whole document.
and it can update a specific nested doc property using script only (as per my knowledge) that is also a heavy process to ES5.

Comment: @torzonhot Yes, that's right. If indexing becomes a problem you can use tips from [Tune for indexing speed](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.6/tune-for-indexing-speed.html#_increase_the_refresh_interval), like increasing the refresh interval.